# automatically set database ID in CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-4.2

I have two entities, ParkingType and Exception, there's a OneToMany relation between them, since each ParkingType can have multiple exceptions.

I made it so whenever I create a new ParkingType I can also create the exceptions related to it at the same time. I did that by using a CollectionType containing the exception form inside the parkingtype form. the collectiontype is dynamic so I can add as many exceptions as I would like.

**Problem**: the exception table has a column called type_id, which is used to relate that exception to the ParkingType and I have to populate that field myself everytime by choosing from a drop down. I don't want to do that, I want that field to reference the object that I just created by default.
My code:
Exception entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ExceptionRepository")
 */
class Exception
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datedebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datefin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tempsdebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tempsfin;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeParking", inversedBy="exceptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(?string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatedebut(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datedebut;
    }

    public function setDatedebut(?\DateTimeInterface $datedebut): self
    {
        $this->datedebut = $datedebut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatefin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datefin;
    }

    public function setDatefin(?\DateTimeInterface $datefin): self
    {
        $this->datefin = $datefin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTempsdebut(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->tempsdebut;
    }

    public function setTempsdebut(?\DateTimeInterface $tempsdebut): self
    {
        $this->tempsdebut = $tempsdebut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTempsfin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->tempsfin;
    }

    public function setTempsfin(?\DateTimeInterface $tempsfin): self
    {
        $this->tempsfin = $tempsfin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?TypeParking
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?TypeParking $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

ParkingType Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TypeParkingRepository")
 */
class TypeParking
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=55)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time", nullable=true)
     */
    private $tempsmax;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourdebut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $jourfin;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Exception", mappedBy="type", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $exceptions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->exceptions = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTempsmax(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->tempsmax;
    }

    public function setTempsmax(\DateTimeInterface $tempsmax): self
    {
        $this->tempsmax = $tempsmax;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJourdebut(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->jourdebut;
    }

    public function setJourdebut(\DateTimeInterface $jourdebut): self
    {
        $this->jourdebut = $jourdebut;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJourfin(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->jourfin;
    }

    public function setJourfin(\DateTimeInterface $jourfin): self
    {
        $this->jourfin = $jourfin;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Exception[]
     */
    public function getExceptions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->exceptions;
    }

    public function removeException(Exception $exception): self
    {
        if ($this->exceptions->contains($exception)) {
            $this->exceptions->removeElement($exception);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($exception->getType() === $this) {
                $exception->setType(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function addException(Exception $exception)
    {
        $this->exceptions->add($exception);
    }

}
```

ParkingType Form:

```
<?php


class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')





           ->add('exceptions', CollectionType::class, [
            'label'        => 'Exception',
            'entry_type'   => Exception1Type::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype'    => true,
            'required'     => false,
            'by_reference' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'attr'         => [
                'class' => 'collection',
            ],
        ])


        ;
                $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'See my addresses',
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Exception Form:

```
class ExceptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder            

        ->add('nom')
        ->add('datedebut')
        ->add('datefin')
        ->add('tempsdebut')
        ->add('tempsfin')
        ->add('type',EntityType::class, [
            'class' => TypeParking::class,
            'choice_label' => 'libelle',
        ])        

 ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Exception::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can just set the type by yourself in php, plus, you don't have to include all fields in the form...

Comment: I removed the field completely from my form, I just want it to get the newly created ParkingType's ID by default. I couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: see my answer ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the field from the `ExceptionType`* and in your `ParkingType`, change the `addException`:

```
public function addException(Exception $exception)
{
    $this->exceptions->add($exception);
    $exception->setType($this); // <-- this is new.
}
```

**update**: you also have to set the exceptions `CollectionType` option `by_reference` to `false`, such that the adder is actually called by the form component.

this is *one* way to do it. the other option is to do this in your controller and call `setType` for every Exception you find in the ParkingType ...

*) this assumes, you don't edit the Exception on its own, ever. otherwise, either conditionally add the parking-type form field on certain options, or use a different form for Exceptions (for example named `ParkingTypeExceptionType`) that doesn't adds a form field for parking type.

Comment: Still the same thing, maybe it's because the ParkingType's ID is set to be autogenerated. So it's only generated by the database. Is there any other way around to get this to work ?

Comment: this should already work, tbh. you did remove the type field from the exceptiontype form and modified addException?

Comment: yeah I did, I tried removing that function all together and it didn't change anything, I don't thing that function even worked to begin with since It managed to add exception even without it.

Comment: ah, according to https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/by-reference-adder-remover you also have to set `by_reference` to false, otherwise it will just fetch a reference via the getter (it's an `ArrayCollection`) and modify that directly.

Comment: ah wait I got it to work, sorry man my mistake,  'by_reference'  was set to true so I set it back to false which, I think, forced it to use the add function.